# jQuery Multiple Forms Submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 forms on a page. I know that forms cannot be nested.

`<form id="form1"></form>`

`<form id="form2"></form>`

`<form id="form3"></form>`

`<form id="form4"></form>`

presented in that order.

Form 1 and Form 4 post to same php page for processing.
Form 1 have 1 input field
Form 4 have multiple fields, checkboxes and selects.

What is the best approach for both form 1 or form 4 sending the combined fields of both forms?

I've tried jQuery, works great for text input and checkbox, but can't get it to work with Select.
Tried combining form 1 and form 4 and using css to repositioning form 1, but can't get the layout right.

Is there something simpler to do this?

Answer (score 11):

It's not possible. You can either use `serialize()` or `serializeArray()` method for getting forms' data and post them to the server using Ajax:

> Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

```
$('#send').click(function() {
   var firstFormData  = $('form:eq(0)').serializeArray();
   var fourthFormData = $('form:eq(3)').serializeArray();
   $.ajax({
        url  : '...',
        type : 'post',
        data : firstFormData.concat(fourthFormData)
   }).done(function() {
       // ...
   });
});
```

Comment: @undefined Thanks, actually .serialize is the first thing I've tried.   Doesn't seem to capture checkbox array.  Then I tried :  $('#form4 :input').not(':submit').clone().hide().appendTo('#form1');  That works great with all Inputs but not <Select> Tags =(

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I could not get .serialize() to work with checkbox array from form4 e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="model[]">
```

I tried to grab checked values but could not get them to serialize together with other input :

```
var vals = []
    $('input:checkbox[name="model[]"]').each(function() {
        if (this.checked) {
            vals.push(this.value);
        }
    });
```

So I went back and did the simpler thing :

Removed form1, move the text input and the submit button within a `<div id="searchbox" style="position:abosulte;top:-100px;left:0px;">My original form1</div>` inside form4.

Put a placeholder `<div id="placeholder" style="position:relative;"></div>` above form2 and 3 where form1 used to be.

Place a javascript above :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#searchbox")
    .appendTo("#placeholder");
});
```

to move the text input and submit button to position them absolute and relative to the placeholder div.

This way I reduced them to 1 form (which is what its intention anyways), does not rely on javascript to manipulate any data, and does not require me to do the tandem serialization on both forms.