# JQuery multiple form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Multiple Forms Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373361/jquery-multiple-forms-submit)

The following code is the JQuery part

```
    $("form").validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post('bin/Profile.php', $("form").serialize(), function(data) {
                $('#ProfileWall').prepend(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

After this I have multiple forms. The < form > id is unique and each form has different information within a hidden < input > but all inputs have the same id. When I submit, any of the forms, it always submits the values of the last form. Can anyone help me modify this code to support all my forms. (The forms are generated by a while loop which is extracting information from a mysql database)

Comment: Further, for @FaizanHaq, using duplicate IDs for different hidden fields is rarely the right thing to do.  Use duplicate `name` attributes or duplicate `class` attributes, but not `id`s.