# submit multiple forms using JQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have this code to submit 1 form on click.

```
$('#verify_id').click(function() { 
var formData = new FormData($('form#verify_id_form')[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/public_transaction/verify_id',
    data: formData,
    async: false,
    success: function (res) {
        alert(res);
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
return false;
});
```

But, I want to submit 2 more forms with this. How can I change `data` to submit multiple forms?
ID of other 2 forms are: `#form1` and `#form2`. How can I modify this line?

```
var formData = new FormData($('form#verify_id_form')[0]);
```

**EDIT**

there is a option in ajax to do something like this...

```
var dataString = $("#filter-group1, #filter-group2").serialize();
(here 2 forms are getting submitted bu just 1 click)
```

But, I don't know how to achieve this in my case?

Comment: 3 forms, 3 request. Unless you can condense them into 1 request but your end point would have to be setup to handle such a operation.

Comment: You can't `POST` multiple forms in one request. You can merge the form values, submit one after the other, sure. But not multiple forms at once.

Comment: Those are form ID. I want to submit 3 forms together.

Comment: Please, Check my edit in question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373361/jquery-multiple-forms-submit

Comment: @Alex7  I am creating form object here. that is the case of serialization.

Comment: Why don't you use 3 ajax requests with async:true when the button is clicked? 3 forms will be submitted..

Comment: @plbsam : can you explain me with an example?

Comment: @RonakPatel you repeat your code inside click method 3 times for each form with async true

Comment: @Alex7 : ok.. let me try that thing

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use "ajax:false" and submit all 3 forms, as $.ajax is asynchronous all the forms will be submitted in non-blocking way.

```
$('#verify_id').click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
        //code for form 1
    });
    $.ajax({
        //code for form 2
    });
    $.ajax({
        //code for form 3
    });
    return false;
});
```